# Maintaining large numbers of Concordion scripts

Tags: bdd, concordion

I am currently working for a large organisation with about 2k developers working in our IT department. We maintain many things including our e-commerce platform and there are currently about 30 projects currently impacting that.

Recently all of our teams have been instructed to deliver a series of automated tests using Concordion and Selenium Webdriver. For a while this has been going fairly well and many tests have been created but lately maintaining the existing tests while our e-commerce platform constantly changes has been somewhat of a nightmare. We have thousands of test scripts covering many parts of our website but there does not seem to be any facility in Concordion to split scripts into reusable compartments which could then be maintained once, rather than having to make changes to hundreds of HTML files for one change.

How are other people approaching this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for sharing your experience with us. It’s great to hear / read about large scale application of behavior driven development / specification by example.

One approach that could help you is to focus on key examples (http://gojko.net/2014/05/05/focus-on-key-examples). During specification workshops the entire team is working to get a common understanding of the new user needs and requirements. Then you go on and write specification documents containing key examples. There you should not try to cover everything, but to write only as many examples as necessary to express the common understanding.
Additionally, you should try to identify concepts, on which the examples are based. Are there some examples related to a similar topic – this is probably an underlying concept. It is often easier to understand the examples, if they focus just on one concept (e.g. the validation of a card number). Each concept can be usually described with only a few examples.

Do you have any other types of automated tests (e.g. unit tests)? Are you experiencing the same maintainability challenges with these other tests? Could you use good practices from these other test types to improve your Concordion approach?

Could you tell us more about your setup? How many active specifications have you already created within your company?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your detailed answer. Our backend code is generally quite well unit-tested. The legacy code tends to have problems with the unit-tests as changes in one class sometimes cause errors to cascade into other classes. We unfortunately haven't implemented a test first strategy so we only really change the jUnits after they cause the build to fail.

We are using a combination of Concordion and Selenium WebDriver to test our front end. There is some code linking into a stubbing environment. There are currently several thousand specifications in our company.

Answer (score 4):

The goal of Concordion is not to implement test scripts as HTML, but rather for the HTML to describe the behaviour that you are testing (*what* you are trying to achieve). The implementation details (*how* it is being tested) are implemented as Java code. This code can then be structured with an appropriate level of abstraction so that each change to the system under test only requires a change to one part of the code.

Your HTML specifications should only need to change on the rare occasions that the business rules change.

These concepts are described further on the [Hints and Tips](http://concordion.org/Technique.html) tab of the Concordion home page.